# Uploading and saving a file to IIS virtual directory outside the root folder

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-8

Based on Microsoft's website as well as even this forum the general consensus seems to be to keep uploaded user files from the website outside of the wwwroot folder (C:\inetpub\wwwroot) and even better outside of the system drive. I have setup a virtual directory(C:\inetpub\files) in IIS for my file uploads which is outside of the wwwroot but still on the C drive (we only have one drive and I cannot partition it to make another drive). So hopefully this is still considered secure in that aspect! My issue however is I use the following code to get the directory to my hosting enviroment:

```
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, document.DOCUMENT_LOCATION);
                    var fileName = document.FILENAME_AFTER_UPLOAD;
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
```

I am not sure exactly what file path I am suppose to use for saving to virtual directory. The virtual directory has an alias of "files" so its virtual path is /files so do I use env.WebRootPath + "/files" or is there some other way to access the virtual directory/path? For background document is a model object from a SQL query that returns my file path to save to and the filename we create in the SQL server.

Comment: Do you mean to upload the file to the path specified like C drive or D drive?

Comment: I wanted to use the env.webrootpath in the ihostenviroment namespace to keep my code more dynamic. However I stored my files upload folder outside of that in the parent directory of env.webrootpath thinking it would make it more secure since it’s outside of wwwroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,you want to upload a file outside of that in the parent directory of env.webrootpath means wwwroot folder.so for that try this below code:-

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/img", document.Document.FileName);
```

above, `env.webrootpath` no need to use because you want to path more dynamic.

Or if you want to upload to C drive instead of wwwroot.

```
string SavePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), (@"C:\", model.FormFile.FileName);
```

Comment: The asp.net core project comes with a wwwroot folder with the js, css, and img folders etc. When you start a fresh site in IIS the wwwroot folder is the public folder. So it is strange I have a wwwroot folder inside of a wwwroot folder. Should I adjust my IIS site such that the public folder is the child wwwroot?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 if you have two wwwroot folder,you can delete one.or you can adjust that.the main thing is your path right or not.

Comment: It is just strange all the templates for asp.net core apps in visual studio include a wwwroot folder when really shouldnt the wwwroot folder contain all of the additional files such as startup.cs, etc.? I decided to shift my IIS site's path such that it goes to the child wwwroot with the css, js, and img library and the site would not load which makes me think the wwwroot folder included in the VS templates should not be called wwwroot.